# dynamically select range of mysql columns using php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello and thanks for your time!

I'm trying to pull data from a mysql table using PHP, and am fairly new to both mysql and php.
I have a table built on racing information, where the following race results are recorded:
Date, Type, WL1, L1, L2, etc up to L15

WL1 column contains a value from L1 to L15, and stands for "winning lane 1" - basically what lane the car was in that came in first place. 
Columns L1 to L15 contain racers' names.
Given the above, I'm trying to display the following in a table:

Date, Type, WL1 and the value of L1 through L15 as "Winner" when the data in columns L1 through L15 match the entry in column WL1.

Example:

```
-----------------------------------------
Date   | Type    | WL1| Winner
-----------------------------------------
May 5  | Rally   | 13 | John
May 7  | Stock   | 2  | Stewart
May 15 | Touring | 7  | Eddy
```

I'm able to achieve results like this using the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM races";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Date</th>";
                echo "<th>Type</th>";
                echo "<th>WL1</th>";
                echo "<th>Winner</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Type'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['WL1'] . "</td>";
                if($row['WL1'] == 'L1'){
                    echo "<td>" . $row['L1'] . "</td>";
                }elseif($row['WL1'] == 'L2'){
                    echo "<td>" . $row['L2'] . "</td>";
```

That being said, I'm thinking there has to be an easier way than iterating through 15 values with if/elseif statements.  I've tried both "while" and "for" loops with incremental values, but I only get empty results or errors, most likely due to my inexperience. I've also reproduced the above using a complex CASE statement in MySQL, but again, I'm trying to reduce lines of code.

If someone could suggest a more concise method of pulling this data, either through a MySQL statement or PHP code, I'd appreciate it.  Even better if you can point to some good online examples/tutorials - the whole "teach a man to fish" thing...

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure is what is causing your problem; you should really have a table that links racers and lanes for each race and then `JOIN` to that. Having said that, you can simplify your existing code by noting that the value in `$row['WL1']` is the column name of the winner, so you can simply replace your `if` structure with:

```
echo  "<td>" . $row[$row['WL1']] . "</td>";
```

I've created a sample data structure [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0edfe/4) with `races`, `lanes` and `racers` tables. To query from this structure you would do something like:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(r.Date, '%b %e') AS Date, r.Type, r.Winner AS WL1, rs.Name AS Winner
FROM races r
JOIN lanes l ON l.Race = r.id AND l.Lane = r.Winner
JOIN racers rs ON rs.id = l.Racer
```

Which for my sample data gives:

```
Date    Type        WL1     Winner
May 5   Rally       13      John
May 7   Stock       2       Stewart
May 15  Touring     7       Eddy
```